# How to find enabled workflow folders in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, workflow

I want to find all the folders of my Liferay instance that have an enabled workflow.

In the table "workflowdefinitionlink" there are all the links between workflows and folders but when I disable one workflow on a folder, the row still exists in this table. Rows only disappear when I select "no workflow" but if I select "Use document type restrictions and workflow of the parent folder.", the row is still in the table although workflow is disabled.

Does anyone knows how to retrieve (from database) the list of workflow enabled folders ?

Although there is a column "classPk" in the same table but I can't figure out what it is pointing to ? It's not a folderId.

Thanks for your knowledge !

Comment: Rather than directly going for the DB,did you made attempts at available Liferay APIs to access the same?

Comment: Hi Shivam, I have an underlying issue with workflow, that's why I needed to go deep ^^. Do you have a Liferay service in mind that can help me list workflow activated folders ?

Comment: I looked in the Liferay API and all that I found is a method to list workflow definitions, but not the link between folders/workflow definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact there's no way to see that link in the database. I only found a table that links folders and workflows but even if workflow is disabled on a folder, the record is still in the table. If you select "no worfklow", then the record is deleted but if you select the "parent workflow" option the record remains.

There is no API to list real enabled workflow on folders. That's sad.